# Can I trace record source in Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark

While processing multiple files in parallel with Spark I'd like to know from which file particular record is coming. My goal is to assign file ID (or at least file name) to each record for internal audit purposes.
Is there any way to do this?

I'm using Spark Java API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use [`SparkContext.wholeTextFiles`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html) which gives you the file name as the key and the whole file as the value. If `sc` is a SparkContext (JavaSparkContext in your case), just call `sc.wholeTextFiles("path/to/dir/")`

**P.S.:** I answered a similar question before and discovered that this function does have issues reading compressed files (only tested with gzip) so be aware of that.

Comment: Thank you aaronman. Does previous versions of spark has such capabilities. I forgot to mention what I still on Spark 0.9.1

Comment: @soroka21 it does not have it, upgrade or checkout the [implementation on github](https://github.com/apache/spark), if you're using a dependency management system like maven (which you should be) upgrading is super easy